# django authetication and post error , Getting Different user post when using request.user.is_autheticated

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-authentication

Here below is my code :

```
  from django.db import models
  from django.utils import timezone
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  from django.urls import reverse
  from django.conf import settings


class Post(models.Model):
 STATUS_CHOICES = (('draft', 'Draft'),('published', 'Published'),)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique_for_date='publish',blank=True)
 author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 body = models.TextField()
 publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
 created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
 status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')
 image=models.FileField(null=True,blank=True)


 class Meta:
     ordering = ('-publish',)

 def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])


 def __str__(self):
     return self.title
```

Here below is views.py code ,

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
     from django.views.generic import 
     TemplateView,ListView,DetailView,CreateView
     from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
     from .models import Post
     from .forms import PostForm
     from django.contrib.auth.models import User






class HomePageView(ListView):

model = Post
template_name = 'home.html'


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['deeppost'] = 
Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user.is_authenticated)
    return context





 class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'about.html'




 class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
  model = Post
  template_name = 'post_detail.html'


 class PostNewView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
  template_name = 'new_post.html'
  form_class = PostForm




  def form_valid(self, form):
      form.instance.author = self.request.user
      return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here below is my html

```
-->
 {% extends 'base.html' %}

 {% block content %}

<h1>Homepage.</h1>

 <ul>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
 {% for post in deeppost %}
 <li>{{post.title}}</li></a><p>{{post.body}}</p><p>
  {% if post.image %}<img src="{{post.image.url}}" width="100" height="100">
  {% endif %}</p>Created by-{{post.author}}

  {% endfor %}
  <h2><a href="{% url 'new_post' %}">Create a New Post </a></h2>
  {% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in. Please goto the login Page by clicking on the 
    login 
   link above </p>

 {% endif %}
 </ul>-
 {% endblock %}
```

The problem is i have only 1 users , superuser and testingaccount , Now before i added a filefield and made migrations , it was working file , and posts only created by the relevant user were showing , after i made migrations , only posts from the superuser are showing , I do not understand the problem

Comment: correction 2 users , and it was working fine ultil i added the filefield to the model

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please take a little time to indent your code carefully. It really helps. Clearly state what the code is doing and what you expect it to do. Other users may want to try to run your code locally to make sure their answer is correct.  Make sure you provide enough information for them to do that.

Comment: Will do thanks , i am new to this so just getting used to it